# What is the equivalent in Chinese for the English word "horny"?

Tags: word-requests

As Mr. Confucius said, 食色性也, food and sex play important roles in one's life, when you wants to eat, there is a word in Chinese 饿 to illustrate this state, but there seems no such a word in Chinese to describe the situation when you are horny, or perhaps there is, but beyond my knowledge. So anybody can help?

Answer (score 3):

> [Horny](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/horny)
>
> *4. (Slang: Vulgar): lustful; sexually excited*.
>
> [發情](http://www.cantonese.sheik.co.uk/dictionary/words/41781/)
>
> *be horny; libidinous*
>
> Examples:
>
> He is **horny** - 他在**發情**
>
> Horny woman -  **發情的**女人
>
> Horny man - **發情的**男人

To be subtle, you can use 亢奮

> [亢奮](http://www.cantonese.sheik.co.uk/dictionary/words/57147/)
>
> *very excited*
>
> Examples:
>
> He is **horny** - 他**亢奮**起來

Comment: 发情 seems to describe animals. If I want to say I am horny to my wife, can I say 我发情 to her? It sounds ridiculous, doesn't it?

Answer (score 1):

**发骚**

*CC-CEDICT*

> 1 horny
>
> 2 lecherous

Comment: Such word might be used for a woman in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

饥渴，example, “你太饥渴了！” meaning you are sexually thirsty.

Comment: That is figuratively speaking, but I'd like to know if there is any simple word in real use for that purpose with literal meaning.

Comment: there are several words that can express it, but it depends the situations  what word should be used. besides the words already mentioned above, there are more, 性欲，性感，欲火焚身，欲火中烧......